# Muchas gracias a todos en Stackoverflow

Tags: discusión

Tal vez no sea el tema apropiado para este sitio, pero me arriesgaré a hacerlo.

Quiero agradecer muy sinceramente y de todo corazón a todas las personas que participan en este sitio, preguntando, respondiendo, ayudando, colaborando y acompañando a todo ese grupo de personas que como yo, nos iniciamos en un lenguaje y tratamos hacer de esto una actividad remunerada.

El año pasado me contactó una persona quien me preguntó si le podía construir un sistema que vendiera y controlara el stock en bodega, pues tenía un pequeño que negocio que estaba creciendo y que ciertas operaciones las debía automatizar por muchas razones. Yo, le dije qué sí podía; eso fue en agosto, pero que debería comenzar en septiembre la construcción. Yo llevaba ya casi 1 año sin empleo, con una familia, esposa y tres hijos pequeños; estaba desesperado. Entre agosto y septiembre revisé mucho material en la web y decidí construir en PHP-JavaScript-JQuery-MySql y me puse a estudiar cada una de estas cosas. Fue una experiencia muy árida, en septiembre levanté los requerimientos, diseñé el modelo de base de datos, algunos borradores de las pantallas y me puse a programar. Fueron muchos días acostándome a las 3, 4 de la madrugada o a veces pasaba de largo sin dormir; era una mezcla entre el deseo de aprender, lo entretenido y maravilloso de la lógica del sistema y la sensación de tener el trasero encañonado con una escopeta, pues ya me había comprometido y de eso dependía lograr dinero para mi familia.

Leí todo en Google, vi cientos de vídeos en Youtube y cuando habían temas que no encontraba apoyo, encontré StackOverflow en ingles y luego en español; fue realmente una bendición. Es una comunidad de personas que me ayudaron excepcionalmente; encontré apoyo, solidaridad, preocupación, entrega y eso me permitió resolver problemas que de otra forma no había podido solucionar.
Me embarga un profundo sentimiento de agradecimiento, pues gracias a todos Uds, logré terminar el sistema, ponerlo en producción y que me pagaran. Pude hacer una bella cena de navidad y de año nuevo con mi familia.

Aprendí PHP, JavaScript, JQuery y MySql. Ahora estoy aprendiendo Bootstrap y otras cosas para evolucionar el sistema y hacer otros en otras áreas. Mi cliente está evaluando otras funcionalidades que necesita agregar al sistema, lo cual será más trabajo y nuevos recursos.

Gracias a todos y cada uno de Uds.

Comment: Muchas felicidades Junco, la mejor manera que tienes para agradecer es apoyar respondiendo preguntas a nuestros colaboradores, Saludos

Comment: da mucha alegría saber que entre todos crecemos, el motor de esta industria es el compartir entre desarrolladores de todos los niveles, siempre estamos aprendiendo y mejorando. Te aporto un granito de arena, revisa estos sitios web para que sigas dándole con todo el power 2.0! https://hackr.io/ - http://tutorialspoint.com - http://mva.microsoft.com - http://udemy.com - http://www.class-central.com - http://www.miriadax.net que sigan los éxitos! bendiciones hermano :D un gusto enorme leer "preguntas" de este nivel :D

Comment: Es grato ver que una persona se supera ante las adversidades y las convierte en oportunidades. Sigue estudiando que uno nunca termina de aprender y suerte.

Comment: Me alegro muchísimo que hayas tenido una experiencia positiva, y ver que el esfuerzo es reconocido... Si me permitís preguntarte, ¿recordás cómo fue el paso de [so] a [es.so]? ¿Fue por el banner de publicidad que aparece? ¿revisando la lista de sitios de la red? ¿o alguien te lo comentó?

Comment: Felicidades @Junco por lograr tus objetivos.

Comment: Volví a entrar en meta y quisiera volver a votar esta "pregunta".. gracias Junco.

Comment: ¡Felicidades Junco! Siempre estaremos en constante aprendizaje, la diferencia es que ahora ya serás el último eslabón de la cadena, ahora te toca guiar y ayudar a personas que al igual que algunos de nosotros hemos necesitado un empujoncito para seguir adelante. Nunca olvides tus inicios porque seguramente llegarás muy lejos :D