# Mostrando a la comunidad Stack Overflow en español lo que ha logrado su esfuerzo

Tags: discusión

estoy tratando de convertir un programa en una app-android para móviles. Y la verdad es que estoy obteniendo mucho apoyo de esta comunidad. Sin ánimo de autopromocionarme, cuando lo tenga listo me gustaría mostrarselo a los usuarios que me han ayudado cómo una forma de decirles "gracias a vosotros lo he conseguido". ¿Hay algún modo del que pueda hacer esto?

Comment: Me refiero a la comunidad stackoverflow español

Comment: En lugar de usar los comentarios para hacer aclaraciones sobre el contenido de la pregunta, [edit] la pregunta. En esta ocasión lo hice por tí, pues también había que cambiar la etiqueta.

Comment: Puedes ponerlos en los creditos de tu aplicacion. Saludos

Comment: o tambien puedes pasar el link en el chat. Saludos

Comment: En el chat puedes compartir imagenes o el url de tu aplicación, hay muchos usuarios que pueden dar puntos de vista para mejorar aún más tu aplicación.

Comment: Justo en [esta pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1395/muchas-gracias-a-todos-en-stackoverflow) otro usuario expresó el mismo sentimiento :D

Answer (score 7):

Es fantástico que esta comunidad te esté ayudando tantísimo. No me cuento entre los expertos de Android, pero me da una inmensa alegría pensar que aquí podré encontrar ayuda de la buena si algún día me adentro en ese mundo.

Tal y como te han indicado en los comentarios, puedes agradecerlo en los créditos de la aplicación.

Además, y para mí más importante, anímate a devolver el favor a la comunidad transmitiendo todo el conocimiento que vas obteniendo. Eso lo puedes hacer contestando a las preguntas que otros tengan, pero también poniendo el código en algún repositorio abierto, para que otros puedan disfrutar de lo que has programado y utilizarlo en sus quehaceres.
En inglés a eso le llaman "pay it forward" (podríamos traducirlo como *cadena de favores*) y el fundador de Stack Overflow habló de ello en [¿Cómo dar las gracias a los usuarios que responden a mis preguntas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1625/83).

Comment: comparto la idea hermano, se siente muy gratificante que la comunidad ayude a crear :D

Answer (score 1):

Me alegra que la comunidad te haya podido ayudar.

Mencionar a los usuarios de SO que te han ayudado y/o el sitio en los créditos sería una buena forma de agradecimiento.

No olvides atribuir el código que uses a los usuarios que lo han proporcionado. Todo el código que ves en SOes está licenciado bajo [CC-BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) por los autores del código. Si no cumples con los requisitos de esa licencia podrías tener problemas legales, en teoría. Cuanto más éxito tenga tu juego, en términos monetarios, más cerca estará la práctica de la teoría.