# ¿Están o estarán permitidas las preguntas de agradecimiento a la comunidad?

Tags: discusión

> **Espero no parecer el malo de la pelicula.**

Me gustaria que el **CM** o algun **moderador** determinara o creara un post si lo cree oportuno (yo si) para que se vote si seran permitidas este tipo de preguntas "ver abajo".

---

Para poner en contexto cuando regrese despues de un tiempo me encontre con esta pregunta por tener **muchos votos**:

- [Muchas gracias a todos en Stackoverflow](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1395/muchas-gracias-a-todos-en-stackoverflow)

La cual me soprendio de diferente maneras, una fue por la actitud de OP, pero la mas importante fue que no se hubiera cerrado esta pregunta, pues a mi entender este tipo de preguntas no serian "correctas" ni siquiera para el meta, aunque no se, jamas me plantee hacer una pregunta de ese estilo *"yo las gracias con los votos y los check y si acaso un comentario"*, y jamas habia leido algo similar en SO.

Pero no dije nada en meta, guardando a que apareciera algo similar, no es el mismo caso pero por ahi van los tiros:

- [Mostrando a la comunidad Stack Overflow en español lo que ha logrado su esfuerzo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1789/mostrando-a-la-comunidad-stack-overflow-en-espa%C3%B1ol-lo-que-ha-logrado-su-esfuerzo)

Entiendo que a la comunidad de ahora mismo, le gustan este tipo de preguntas, lo digo por lo votos que tienen, asi que me gustaria como dije que se creara un tema para votar si esto sera permitido, o no, antes de que aparezcan cientos de esta publicaciones, *aunque quizas nunca pase*.

---

Konamiman hizo un post para la definicion del sitio en su dia:

- [Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/161/definici%C3%B3n-de-la-tem%C3%A1tica-apropiada-para-el-sitio)

tomado esto mas o menos como ejemplo para que se entienda lo que quiero decir.

Comment: si se entra en https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes yo espero encontrarme con con cosas importante o relevante para con el sitio "sin animo de ofender al OP de la pregunta mencionada". Como son las preguntas que aparecen cuando las ordenas por votos, menos esta que se menciona, que esta en el **segundo lugar** y si la tendencia continua es posible que se llenen las primeras paginas de preguntas similares. Como anecdota pues estaria bien siempre bajo mi punto de vista, bloquearla y dejarla pero el resto que vengan umm no se yo. Saludos

Comment: jaja aunque yo directamente las prohibiria, *pues de las votaciones ya se sabe que no siempre sale lo mas sensato*, en este caso para el sitio y la repercusion que esto tendria, como lo mencionado de ordenar por votos como lo de que te pueda apacer cantidad de estas pregunta en el panel **PUBLICACIONES POPULARES EN META** en algun momento pues la comunidad cada vez es mas grande, aunque si se decide por votacion, tanto como si se aceptan como si no, tampoco es que se hunda el barco.Saludos

Comment: Lo que mencionas de Konamiman es válido para el sitio SOes, las preguntas que indicas están en meta. No veo que estén proliferando esta especie de preguntas e inundando el meta, por lo que de momento solo les diría: si quieres ser agradecido con el sitio entonces participa más: vota a favor, responde preguntas y que siga creciendo el conocimiento entre pares.

Comment: Mejor esas publicaciones que las de los _"indignados"_.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza gracias por contestar, si su cometario indica como procede usted -> *...momento solo les diría...* que me parece bien tambien se les puede inviar a el link de lo que tradujo fedroqui y me parece acertado, pero con este post buscaba algo similar a lo que contesto Juan por ejemplo algo que dejara claro si llegado el momento esto seria permitido. Si lo hubiera comentando solo con la primera pregunta que aparecio no es que fuera incorrecto pero podria asemejarse a optimizar antes de tiempo, pero con la segunda bajo mi punto de vista ya se esta empezando a notar el cuello de botella

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza...es mas ahora mismo en el panel de **PUBLICACIONES POPULARES EN META** ya me aparece esta -> *8 Mostrando a la comunidad Stack Overflow en español lo que ha logrado su esfuerzo* cosa que ayer no me aparecia, gracias por su tiempo.Saludos

Comment: @toledano *Mejor esas publicaciones que las de los "indignados"* una cosa menos mala que otra no la convierte en una cosa buena, aunque siempre depende del punto de vista, pero centrandonos, en este sitio, una pregunta de un indignado posiblemente pueda aportar mas (no siempre) pero si se queja abra que escuharlo y quizas tenga razon y eso ayuda a mejorar el sitio y pulir los detalles, no confundir un indiganacion de alguien con una pregunta bien formular que uno diciendo groserias. En cambio este...

Comment: @toledano ...tipo de preguntas, pues no se si aportaran algo a sitio mas alla de que alguno se pueda sertir bien al leerla por x motivos. Saludos

Comment: Angel: he editado el título para centarlo en la duda exacta, no en cómo o quién quieres te la conteste :) Por supuesto, revierte el cambio si no lo compartes.

Comment: @fedorqui nada sin problema, esta bien asi, lo que pasa es que quizas puse el titulo anterior, porque no sabia si se crearia un consenso para determinar esto, o el CM ya tenia una idea de como se trataria este tema, pues pensaba que este tema era algo delicado en el que el CM tendria por decirlo de alguna manera mayor peso de desicion, espero entienda el porque puse ese titulo, pero reitero que esta bien como lo dejo y gracias por ello. Saludos

Comment: Angel: sí, tenía toda la razón de ser del mundo. Ahora que el CM se pronunció, podemos darnos por contestados oficialmente :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Estas respuestas/preguntas/publicaciones **no se permiten** en los sitios de nuestra red. Pero, siendo que somos un sitio que actualmente esta en "beta" decidí dejarlas tal y como las encontré porque quise que otros vieran (por un tiempo solamente) lo que el compartir con otros puede producir - en este caso, el agradecimiento de la actividad entre los usuarios de esta comunidad.

En cuanto el sitio se gradúe, no se permitirán estas preguntas. Seguiremos lo indicado en [esta publicación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1624/c%C3%B3mo-dar-las-gracias-a-los-usuarios-que-responden-a-mis-preguntas) la cual contiene la posición oficial de nuestra red.

[¿Cómo dar las gracias a los usuarios que responden a mis preguntas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1624/4)

Comment: Me alegra que contestara Juan, es lo que me imaginaba mas o menos, ahora por lo menos **queda plasmado cual sera el camino a seguir en un futuro** y el porque se permitian, me alegra saber eso, por otro lado aprovechar para felicitarlo por el buen trabajo realizado y conseguido desde que inicio el sitio, siempre aparecen piedras en el camino lo importante es no pararse, gracias por su tiempo. Saludos

Comment: Hay situaciones en que es razonable actuar diferente en beta de como será tras graduarse. Por ejemplo en la elección de moderadores cuando la comunidad no se conoce a si misma. Pero en este caso, ¿qué justifica el actuar de forma distinta en beta a como será tras graduarse? ¿Por qué otra pregunta sobre la misma temática pero en sentido contrario, y que también era migrada, fue cerrada y esta fue permitida? Esta arbitrariedad no es buena. -1 a quien no respeta sus propias reglas.

Answer (score 5):

Yo no espero en ningun caso que haya *cientos de estas publicaciones*, no es habitual que la gente sea tan agradecida, y de hecho suele ser mas bien al reves, es decir, los usuarios que preguntan parecen exigir una respuesta y muchas veces ni siquiera la votan o aceptan.

Dicho esto, estoy de acuerdo en que este tipo de preguntas no aportan nada a la comunidad mas allá de una auto-complacencia. Como bien contesta @fedorqui en una de las preguntas que enlazas,Jeff Atwood contestó a una pregunta similar con **pay it forward**, es decir, si estás agradecido la forma de demostrarlo es respondiendo preguntas de otros y aportando así a la comunidad. Aqui se tradujo al español [¿Cómo dar las gracias a los usuarios que responden a mis preguntas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1624/15301)

Comment: *...no es habitual que la gente sea tan agradecida...* puede ser pero si el ratio es 0,1 de 1000 personas, si el sitio crece el ratio tambien, con lo que a poco que aparescan preguntas de este tipo, con una cantidad similar de votos ya se empezaria a notar en la ordenacion por votos ect.  Aunque quizas vengan otros que lo que quieran es obtener puntos o ganar visiblidad o cualquier otra cosas y se les empieze ocurrir el crear preguntas de este tipo o variantes.Gracias por contestar.Saludos

Comment: Lo que quiero decir es que me parece lejano que llegue a suponer un problema grave, pero efectivamente estoy de acuerdo contigo y probablemente es mejor atajarlo antes de que se produzca. Veremos que opina la comunidad.

Comment: Gracias por poner el link de @fedroqui ya lo habia leido antes, pero asi queda enlazado.Saludos