# ¿Debe ser toda pregunta en meta una pregunta?

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas

Recientemente he visto a una persona [votar para cerrar una pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1921/por-qu%C3%A9-cualquiera-puede-responder-y-no-cualquiera-puede-preguntar#comment5630_1921)(*) en meta porque:

> Voto para cerrar esta pregunta porque no es una pregunta.

¿Es este un motivo válido para cerrar en meta?
Hay múltiples ejemplos de preguntas que no son preguntas en meta y no se cierran, por ejemplo:
[Pruebas técnicas de la red de Stack Exchange - 3 de mayo 12:00 AM UTC](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1871/pruebas-t%C3%A9cnicas-de-la-red-de-stack-exchange-3-de-mayo-1200-am-utc)

(*)La publicación está borrada, necesitas 2000 de reputación para poder verla.

Comment: En mi opinión esa "pregunta" simplemente carecía de sentido / coherencia.

Comment: @Shaz Ni te lo discuto ni te doy la razón. No es ese el tema que estoy tratando.

Comment: ¿De qué se trataba la publicación?

Comment: @ArtEze Era un usuario quejándose de que no le gusta como funciona SOes. Usando formas maleducadas y además estaba muy mal redactada. Pero ese no es el tema. El tema es si meta es solo para preguntas.

Comment: Es posible que el autor del comentario citado se haya referido a una acepción distinta a la que se refiere esta "pregunta" ... Nota al margen: El día en Monterrey está como para ponerse filosófico, amaneció "llovido", está fresco, jeje, casi casi se antoja preguntar ¿Qué es una pregunta?

Comment: No, no todo tiene que ser una pregunta. Si, si es un motivo válido.

Comment: las "preguntas" de [tag:discusion] no tienen por que serlo xD

Comment: La pregunta no respetaba los mínimos de conducta y respeto a los demás, por lo que considero positivo que se cerrara y borrara.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Meta no es únicamente para preguntas.

Un ejemplo es esta pregunta, [¡Bienvenidos a este su sitio!](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/146/bienvenidos-a-este-su-sitio): En el ejemplo, no está preguntando nada, solo está dando la bienvenida a este sitio.

Otro ejemplo, [Muchas gracias a todos en Stackoverflow](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1395/muchas-gracias-a-todos-en-stackoverflow): En este, solo está dando las gracias y contando la experiencia que tuvo en este sitio.

El problema con la publicación que eliminaron, según me contaste, es simplemente que se falta el respeto a la comunidad.

---

Dejo otro ejemplo, esta vez, no de agradecimiento, [Video introductorio para SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/899/video-introductorio-para-soes): Esto trata sobre una aportación a los videos del canal de Youtube.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Yo quitaría el segundo ejemplo que has puesto puesto que cuando el sitio se gradúe [no estarán permitidas esas publicaciones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1800/301) Mejor poner ejemplos que sí están y estarán permitidos.

Comment: Aqui tiene unas cuantas "preguntas" para apoyar lo que dices si quiere borrar la que comento @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1840/un-poco-m%C3%A1s-de-color-para-soes-en-el-c%C3%B3digo y https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1828/jornada-de-limpieza pienso que ambas se usan para informar, y son bien acogidas. Saludos

Comment: Muy buenas todas estas aclaraciones pero ..... Y si Meta no es únicamente para preguntas entonces por qué posee el mismo formato de preguntas-respuestas? Me parece que a veces pierde mucho sentido, sobre todo cuando marcan aceptada una respuesta a una "pregunta" que no es realmente una pregunta en sí